# Angle to Double or CGFloat or String - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In swift Angle(degrees : 20.0) , So now I want to convert or store that 20.0 in a Double or String or CGFloat .

What is the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of type `Angle` have `degrees` property of type `Double`. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/angle).

```swift
let angle = Angle(degrees: 20)
let degrees = angle.degrees // 20 of type Double
```